# How to pass current Url with query strings into Html.ActionLink() function in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.actionlink

On the `https://www.willistowerswatson.com/en/press` page, select "Exchange Solutions" in the "Services" facet, and note how the query string changes to this:

`https://www.willistowerswatson.com/en/press#sort=%40fdisplayz45xdate47442%20descending&f:@businesssegmentsubl_coveofacets_1=[Exchange%20Solutions]`

Then, when you click the "Subscribe by RSS" button, a new tab opens up with those query string parameters (which were produced by facet selections) preserved.

I want to replicate this behavior now that we are converting our Coveo search to MVC views.  In my Search.cshtml file, for the "Subscribe by RSS" link, I have this code:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Translate.TextByDomain(StringConstants.DictionaryDomains.WTW, "Subscribe by RSS"), "ReturnRSS", "Search", new { @itemId = Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString() }, new { target = "_blank" })
```

The HTML that code produces in my view source is this:

```
<a href="/api/sitecore/Search/ReturnRSS?itemId=%7BE1EB2D45-066F-4F8F-8B9B-049E7918A034%7D" target="_blank">Subscribe by RSS</a>
```

and it successfully calls my `public void ReturnRSS(string itemId)` function in my `public class SearchController : GlassController` class.

My challenge is that I want to also send into that `ReturnRSS(string itemId)` function, the current page URL WITH ITS QUERY STRINGS, which can change AFTER the HTML is rendered, and the facets are selected.  In other words, once "Exchange Solutions" in the "Services" facet is selected, and the "Subscribe by RSS" link is clicked, I want to also send into the "ReturnRSS" function, the `&f:@businesssegmentsubl_coveofacets_1=[Exchange%20Solutions]` parameter.

How can I do that?   Should I maybe call another function other than `@Html.ActionLink`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use an Action Link.
Obviously, you do not know the URL that you wish to send when rendering server-side.

Render only the content that you know can be rendered at that time (i.e the route + the item ID)(custom extension?) and adjust the rest via a JS function.

Ex:

```
button.onClick = () => {
   window.open(getURL(), "_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider another way which uses Javascript/JQuery and does not use an Actionlink.

```
$.fn.GetQueryString = function () {
    var queryString = window.location.search;
    return queryString;
};

$.fn.GoToPage = function (controller, action) {
    var qs = $.fn.GetQueryString();
    var url = baseUrlWWW + '/' + controller + '/' + action + qs;
    window.location.href = url;
};
```